# How to make a table row work properly in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, tags

I have fished up a piece of code like this :

```
<table class="inlineH" border="0" summary="">
<tr>
<th class="select"></th>
<th class="name">My Name </th>
<th class="description">Mob Number </th>
<th class="Job">My Job</th>
</tr> 
</table>
```

After this , I have a for loop using which i am iterating another table in a div like this :

```
<%for (int x=0; x< MyNo; x++ ) {

%>
<div id="manIt">
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<% }%>
```

This stuff works perfectly in mozilla and gives me what i want. But when i try it out in IE, this is what happens to the code :

```
<table class="inlineH" border="0" summary="">
<tr>
<th class="select"></th>
<th class="name">My Name </th>
<th class="description">Mob Number </th>
<th class="Job">My Job<br/></th>
</tr/> 
</table>


<%for (int x=0; x< MyNo; x++ ) {

%>
<div id="manIt">
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td/>
<td>...</td/>
<td>...</td/>
</tr/>
</table>
</div>
<% }%>
```

As you can see, IE is adding an extra "/" to the closing tags: .  I am using IE8.What am i doing wrong here?

**Edit :** Sorry about the IE version. I rechecked it, it's IE 8 .

Kindly help .

Comment: If you're using IE7 then upgrade. So should everybody else. There is absolutely not valid reason for running old browsers in 2012. Even the slowpokes still on Windows XP can upgrade to IE9.

Comment: I understand Maritim the point u r making. But the prob is my client wants it like this . Not really my call. Normally i do stuffs like this in IE 9 and things dont go that much down hill. But here my hands are tied .

Comment: Why are you using <br/> in <th> ?

Comment: Sorry, its typo. Will re edit the code to exclude it .

Comment: @Maritim I agree, but I don't think XP supports IE9

Comment: @Maritim easily said and valid but go tell it to NHS who have 300k employees and where IE6 is still standard and users can;t go willy-nilly installing things. support is still required unfortunately in some scenarios. me i would do this by default: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18440979

Comment: @TheDK Try to run your code via html validator, maybe you have a typo somewhere. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Vucko : yeah that's what i am doing now, hoping that some thing will turn up .

Comment: My bad, IE8 is the latest supported version in XP.

Comment: It seems unlikely that IE 8 is adding extra slashes into your tags. Where are you seeing the extra slash? In View Source?

Comment: Yeah, i was seeing it in view source. But i figured out the problem later. I made a simple mistake in my confounded stupid logic, which caused this mess. Now everything's fine though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use  another type of tagging, such as `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"/>`, instead of `<script> something </script>.`

Comment: That's not a solution. This is jsp code and you cannot  keep it inside a js file. Get real !